# How does a wireless presentation gateway work?

Tags: wireless-networking, gateway, projector, tv

Wireless presentation gateway is just what we need - be able to connect to projector or tv via notebook wireless link.

However i`m curious about how these devices work. Do they send image at some rate to the device and it further translates it to video or can it just display specific file formats?

I read about [WiD130 Wireless Projection](http://teqavit.com/WiD130.html) (the *Why wireless?* tab) and i'm suspicious as it states:

> - Show PowerPoint and/or multi-media presentations
> - Prefect for displaying documents, spreadsheets, and drawings
> - Surf the internet and e-mail
> - User friendly web-based user interface
> - watch movies*, video, or stream music
>
> *Non-Copyright protected material.

Does it parse document/video/audio formats and send it to TV or will it just stream your desktop? Sorry, but reading those marketing materials, it's not obvious for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product just sends the Video signal over the network.  So it's document/format agnostic.

If it has the right connector, then it will work.

For your users, it will appear as a separate monitor.  Windows will default to showing the same image on both the laptop and the projector, but the user can configure it however they like, to the detriment of the IT folks. . .

Comment: The company bought [Intellinet Wireless 300N Presentation Gateway](http://www.intellinet-network.com/en/products/8761) (one of few to support Wireless N Standard). When you connect to router and open webpage - it downloads software you must run in order to show your screen on TV/Projector. Looks like it just sends pictures to that device over wifi. It works really well, except it's not so sharp as if you connect straight to PC (probably because of compression). There is also a video mode if you want to play video files (because if you play video with your desktop, it has very low fps)